# Issue to build a fixed sticky sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap and I'd like my custom horizontal navbar to stick at the top of the page once it reaches it (like [this](http://bone.themanoid.com/pages/menu-classic.html)).
I have tried to add an affix class to my CSS as well as a piece of JS code, but that does not work. What is the issue?
See https://jsfiddle.net/bs7bdpmh/

html

```
<div id="nav" class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar-classic">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Who are we? </a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services Services Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Products Products Products</a>
    </li>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index:10;
}
```

JS

```
$('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height()
      }
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle code works when you add the Bootstrap JavaScript and jQuery dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs7bdpmh/2/)

JS :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > 50){
    $('#nav').addClass('affix');
  }else{
    $('#nav').removeClass('affix');
  }
});
```

Of course, it's not perfect, I let you adapt the CSS code and HTML structure ;)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why with the fix menu the menu items go to the far right of the viewport and and the logo to the far left? (I'd like them to stay within the same container width as the initial menu)

Comment: If you want the same width of the non-fixed menu, you have to specify it
Check the width of this #nav.affix ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using normal bootstrap the solution is easy

```
 <style>
  /* Note: Try to remove the following lines to see the effect of CSS positioning */
  .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
  <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
  <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
  <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
  <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and if you want to change the navbar when you scroll to the bottum just use something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
      {
        $('#nav').addClass('affix');
      }

});
```